# How many ordered pairs of integers $(a,b)$ are there such that $100≤a,b≤200$ and no carrying is required when calculating $a+b$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics

How many ordered pairs of integers $(a,b)$ are there such that $100≤a,b≤200$ and no carrying is required when calculating $a+b$?

What I did was:

The number range was between 100 and 200 including them. So, with 100 [100-200] or 101 numbers can be added. with 101 [100-108], [110-118], ... , [190-198] and 200 or 91 numbers can be added. . . . with 109 11 numbers can be added.

like this with 110-119 total (91+81+71+61+51+41+31+21+11) can be added . . . like this with 190 total 11 numbers can be added and with 200 only 200 can be added.

So, the total numbers are = 101+91+81+71+61+51+41+31+21+11+91+81+71+61+51+41+31+21+11+81+71+61+51+41+31+21+11+71+61+51+41+31+21+11+61+51+41+31+21+11+51+41+31+21+11+41+31+21+11+31+21+11+21+11+11+1 = 1011 + 912+813+714+615+516+417+318+219+1110+1 = 2195

I don't know if it is correct or not.....

Comment: Have you considered what this requirement implies for possible units digits, for example? People here appreciate some indication of what you have tried for simple questions like this, and it (usually) helps to get answers with a suitable level of detail. Please [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4093941/edit) to add something of your own efforts and difficulties.

Comment: I wont give an answer but just a hint that units digit and tens digit sum shouldn't cross 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get a different answer than you do, but I can't follow your calculations.  "Like this" isn't much of an explanation.

I think it's best to do this digit-by-digit.  Let $k$ be the units digit in the first number.  The units digit in the second number can be anything from $0$ through $9-k$, so there are $10-k$ choices.  When $k=0$ we have $10$ choices, when $k=1$, there are $9$ choices, and so on, until when $k=9$ there is only one choice.  That is, we have $10+9+\cdots+1=55$ choices for the units digits.

There is no carry into the tens columns, and there can be no carry out so the same reasoning applies, and there are $55$ choices for the tens column.

If neither of the numbers is $200$ then both hundreds digits are $1$, and we have $55\cdot55=3025$ choices.

If the first number is $200$ then second number can be any of the $101$ possibilities, and if the second number is $200$ the first number can be any of the $101$ possibilities.  We have counted the case where both numbers are $200$ twice, so there are $201$ cases where at least one of the numbers is $200$.

Altogether there are $$3025+201=3226$$ possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was:

The number range was between 100 and 200 including them.
So, with 100 [100-200] or 101 numbers can be added.
with 101 [100-108], [110-118], ... , [190-198] and 200 or 91 numbers can be
added.
.
.
.
with 109 11 numbers can be added.

like this with 110-119 total (91+81+71+61+51+41+31+21+11) can be added
.
.
.
like this with 190 total 11 numbers can be added
and with 200 only 200 can be added.

So, the total numbers are = 101+91+81+71+61+51+41+31+21+11+91+81+71+61+51+41+31+21+11+81+71+61+51+41+31+21+11+71+61+51+41+31+21+11+61+51+41+31+21+11+51+41+31+21+11+41+31+21+11+31+21+11+21+11+11+1 =
101*1 + 91*2+81*3+71*4+61*5+51*6+41*7+31*8+21*9+11*10+1 = 2195

I don't know if it is correct or not.....